# Android app check for user Dropbox accounts on device

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am developing an app to download all the images from Dropbox. I am using `Dropbox Core API` and have followed this example: [Android Dropbox Core API official documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android)

I would like to check if there are an account already opened on the device. In this case I want to get this session, otherwise I will build a new session with the `Dropbox Core API`. Is it that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android) you linked to, when using the Android Dropbox Core API, you can and should store and re-use the resulting access token for a user after they first authorize the app. (This is typically done using `SharedPreferences`.)

On later runs of your app, your app should check wherever it stored the token to see if it has one. If it does, it can try to use that.

If you do have an access token, you can construct an `AndroidAuthSession`, e.g., using this constructor:

https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/android/AndroidAuthSession.html#AndroidAuthSession(com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes, it is already done. The problem is that the user has to login the first time they open my app, but the thing I want to do is: if the user has the Dropbox App installed and there are already an opened account on the device, I would like to know it and in this case somehow take this acces token for the session is already opened. Then the user only has to login in my app if there arent any opened dropbox account on the device.

Comment: No, you can't get an access token automatically from a Dropbox account in the official Dropbox app already on the device. The user needs to explicitly authorize your app in particular.